# How to properly add name of the location text file in eclipse in java into Scanner file reader

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yEH.jpg)I am trying use a text file to read that is in eclipse but it not able to find the text file I put in eclipse.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        BagBase bb = new BagBase();

        System.out.println("Please enter items into the bag: ");
        try {
            start();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
public static void start() throws FileNotFoundException {
        BagBase bb = new BagBase();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String wow;
        File f = new File("C:/Users/sruja/workspace/Prjocet1/src/ListForBag.txt");
        Scanner aa = new Scanner (f);
        wow=aa.nextLine();
        bb.inserItem(wow);
}
}
```

Thank for the help.
I was not sure why this link was not find when I put in same project

Comment: The file looks like it's named `ListForBag` in the image but `ListForBag.txt` in your source.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "a file is in eclipse"?
Is it in a resource folder? What is your project's structure?

If you had the following structure:

```
MyProject/src/main/java/analysis/ResourceReader.java
MyProject/src/main/resources/text.txt
```

Then you could access the text.txt file with the following function (pass the name of a file as a parameter to this function):

```
private static Reader getReaderFromResource(String resourceName) {
    URL resource = ResourceReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    URL url = Objects.requireNonNull(resource);
    String decodedStr = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
    return new FileReader(new File(decodedStr));
}
```

You could then stuff a BufferedReader constructor with an instance obtained by executing this method (remember about handling exceptions!) and eventually read a file line by line.

---

### EDIT

Ok, so having seen what you're trying to do, I'd go with the following:

Create a project (the best would be a maven project), so that you have a structure similar to the one I've already described. It is a good practice to have resources in a seprate folder in a project, not splitted somewhere on your disk.

This code needs some refactoring, but I don't address it in this answer, for the sake of simplicity.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BagBase bb = new BagBase();

    System.out.println("Please enter items into the bag: ");
    try {
        start();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void start() throws FileNotFoundException {
    BagBase bb = new BagBase();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String wow;
    List<String> dataFromFile = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(getReaderFromResource("shoppingList"))) {
        String currentLine = null;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(currentLine); // prints content of a file, just for the record
            dataFromFile.add(currentLine); 
        }

        bb.setBag(dataFromFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Reader getReaderFromResource(String resourceName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    URL resource = test.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    URL url = Objects.requireNonNull(resource);
    String decodedStr = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
    return new FileReader(new File(decodedStr));
}
```

}

Comment: Oh, I can see you've edited your post while I was preparing an answer. Anyway, look at it and try to adjust it to meet your needs.

Comment: sorry about that, but I hope that I made my questions clear